# Objects stored in state don't have array methods available on them

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-reducer

I have an applicate store setup called AppContext when the application initialises a series of API calls are performed to populate the state.

The issue I'm having is that when trying to perform Array functions such as .findIndex, .IndexOf or any subsequent function the system always responds with a `-1` or `undefined`.

I am 100% sure and have tested that the data exists during this operation.

The state in its initial state looks like this:

```
state: {
    users: [], 
    user: { uid: '' }
}
```

The state looks like this:

```
state:{
    users: {
        {uid: '123'},
        {uid: '456'}
    }
    user: {
        uid: '123'
        ... 
    }
}
```

The data returned from the API looks like this:

```
[{ uid: '123' }, {uid: '456'}]
```

I am using `useReducer` to populate the state with the following code:

```
export const UsersReducer = (state: IUserType[], action: actions) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_USERS':
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};
```

This has been loaded into the Context Store as:

```
users: UsersReducer(users, action),
```

and used in an async database call as follows:

```
dispatch({ type: 'SET_USERS', payload: result.data.data });
```

The types for the state are as follows:

```
export type IUserType = {
  uid: string;
}
```

The types for the Payload:

```
export type ActionMap<M extends { [index: string]: any }> = {
  [Key in keyof M]: M[Key] extends undefined ? { type: Key } : { type: Key; payload: M[Key] };
};

type UsersPayload = {
  [AppReducerTypes.SetUsers]: IUserType[];
};

export type UsersActions = ActionMap<UsersPayload>[keyof ActionMap<UsersPayload>];
```

Why does React store arrays as objects in the state? And secondly, why can I not perform array functions on items that should be stored as arrays?

Comment: When you store an array, i don't know why but keys are added to each of your sur object, so you need to use `Object.values` to prevent that. Then you can use `Array.from` to get an array. As for the reason why this happens, I have no idea and would REALLY love to know why. I couldn't find anything about it on the web. However, I think it has something to do with `return {...state}`. You are telling react : "Take my sub items and put them in an object". I used to do the same because i didn't find any solution to fix that.